# How to connect Google App Engine Memcache from remotely

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached

I have a php webapplication running on my webserver.
Now I want to outsource the memcache and would like to try the google cloud/app engine memcache service.

How do I connect to the memcache service from outside (from my webserver)? Is that possible at all?

I found the documentation on how to use the service here
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/#PHP_PHP_memcache_implementation

But I don't see any description on how to connect to the memcache service remotely.

Probably Memcache::addServer() would do the job (http://php.net/manual/de/memcache.addserver.php)
But, where do I find the right settings (host, port, etc) to connect to the service? Still, I am not even sure if this is possible at all.

Thanks for any advice
Georg

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This is not an architectural advise or even a best practise.**

There is no managed endpoint to connect to memcahce in AE environment.

The only way to establish some sort of a link to debug  is to expose the `get` and the `put` via web service as mentioned below.

```
Expose a web-service in appengine and connect remotely.  Secure it by oauth or encrytion.
```